# Ignore creation of field during table creation in modal but getting data by calling native sql procedure in Jpa Interface not as @Transient

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Ignore creation of field during table creation in modal using entity but getting data by calling native SQL procedure in Jpa Interface, not like as @Transient. while fetching needs the result of that field which we avoid during creation.

```
package com.lotus.springboot.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.lotus.springboot.model.view.StudentPaybleAmountMix;
import com.lotus.springboot.utils.Functions;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "trn_cancelled_paid_amount")
public class TrnCancelledPaidAmount extends BaseModel {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private Long transactionId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String trackingId;
    private Double netAmount;
    private String orderId;
  

   
    @Column(name = "no_of_cnt",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Integer noOfCnt;

   
}
```

```
package com.lotus.springboot.repo;

import com.lotus.springboot.model.TrnCancelledPaidAmount;
import com.lotus.springboot.request.FeesCancelledDataRequest;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface TrnCancelledPaidAmountRepo extends JpaRepository<TrnCancelledPaidAmount,Integer> {


    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call cogent_fees_collection.proc_fees_cancelled( :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.instId}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.progTypeId}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.progId}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.sem}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.termId}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.feePayType}, :#{#feesCancelledDataRequest.isGrpBy})")
    List<TrnCancelledPaidAmount> callingProcFeesCancelled(@Param("feesCancelledDataRequest")FeesCancelledDataRequest feesCancelledDataRequest);

}
```

[Output of Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnaHb.png)

Comment: You can use spring data jpa projections like in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: thanks, @nurgasemetey.
I found an alternative solution using Projection. 
Using an Interface of modal class.

Comment: Any alternative annotation or property at model class for doing same.